# Numpy: Turning an index array into an element array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have an index array:

`A = [1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1]`

for another array of values:

`B = [21, 33, 10, 2]`

Then I want a new array:

`C = [B[A[0]], B[[A[1]], ..., B[A[[5]]] = [B[1], B[0], ..., B[1]] = [33, 21, ..., 21]`

How does one do this with numpy arrays?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply numpy indexing when `B` is a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np

A = [1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1]
B = np.array([21, 33, 10, 2])
output = B[A]
print(output) # [33 21  2 10 21 33]
```